# Participles in sentences

Tags: verbs, present-participles

I have a question. With regard to present participles such as sleeping, singing or fishing. When used in the following sentences are they functioning as nouns or verbs.

I am swimming

In my mind, swimming is and action, so I think that it's a verb. When I look online, it lists participles as nouns.

I'm confused!

Comment: You need to distinguish Form from Function. _Participle_ is the name for the _-ing_ **form** of the verb; it's the Present Active Participle, to be precise. That has nothing to do with how it's used. There are [some uses of the present active participle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html) that are main verbs, like the Progressive construction (though only active verbs can do this); there are some other uses that are Gerunds (which are verbs), and still others that are called "participial", which means they can act like adjectives or adverbs.

Comment: What practical application would "knowing" whether *swimming* here "is" a noun or a verb -- or for that matter, an adjective or adverb -- serve? Try testing it by following it with a noun like *ducks* or *races* or *suits*, with a verb like *to win* or *laughing*, with an adjective like *pretty* or *nude* or *nicer* or *friendlier*, or with an adverb like *well, then, soon, deep, later, tomorrow, Tuesday,* or *easily*. Did knowing what *swimming* "is" tell you which of those would be "right" or "wrong"?

Comment: ... No, but classification can help understanding. Terms such as 'present participle' and 'participial adjective'can be of use when explaining the ambiguity in say 'These pupils are trying'.

Comment: @Edwin Wouldn't it be good enough in your example to call *trying* either a verb or an adjective, depending on intended meaning?  Will trying magistrates trying trying cases  try trying judges' patience in the higher courts, or might the try work out and so save on legal costs and delays? :)

Comment: @tchrist We'll never agree on the lumping / splitting issue. Yes, splitting is messy. With ing-forms, there's the quagmire in the midst of the verb / noun / adjective extremes (Quirk examines the verb - noun cline in fair detail). And then you throw in the preposition factor (rightly), which makes the quagmire pyramidal.

Answer (score 0):

In "I am swimming", "swimming" is a verb.  If it were an adjective, you could modify it with "very", but *"I am very swimming" is no good. In "I am confused", "confused" could be an adjective or a verb -- it may be ambiguous; I'm not sure.  But at least, it *can* be an adjective, since we have "I am very confused".  (Note that "killed" is always a participle and never an adjective, so *"He was very killed" is bad.)

We can't use predicate position as a test with coordination, but elsewhere we can devise a test based on the fact that only like categories can be conjoined.  Both -ing verbs and adjectives can modify nouns, as in "the confused athlete"/"the swimming athlete", but *"the confused and swimming athlete" is pretty strange, presumably because we've coordinated different categories: adjective and verb.

(John's answer, given above as a comment, is wrong.  Category is intrinsic to constituents -- function is not separable.)

Comment: *swimming* is most certainly *not* a verb in "I am swimming". The verb is *am*, *swimming* is the participle. A participle is closer to being an adverb than being a verb - after at, it modifies the (auxillary) verb *am*.

Comment: No, @fgp, *am* is an auxiliary, not a verb.  You can tell that by the fact that *am* is inverted to form a yes-no question: *Am I swimming?*.  Verbs don't work that way: **Swims he in the pool?*

Comment: @fgp, see http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/swim.html. All of the progressive forms of the verb swim, use swimming, including the First person present indicative progressive: ***I am swimming***. John Lawler's comment is spot on regardless of Greg Lee's contrary claim: form and function are discrete designations of a participle.

Comment: @fgp: Greg is correct. The main verb is _swimming_. The auxiliary verb is _am_. The first auxiliary verb in an English sentence is inflected for tense (and in the case of _be_ with person and number as well), and all the rest of the verbs in the verb phrase are non-finite forms (infinitive, past participle, or present participle). One can have up to 4 auxiliary verbs in one verb chain: _She **may have been being interrogated** the entire time_. _May, have, been,_ and _being_ are all auxiliaries; _interrogated_ is the (past participle form) main verb. http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf

Comment: @GregLee But by that can-I-invert-to-form-a-question logic, *am* also wouldn't be the verb in "I am here" - asking "Am I here?" is perfectly valid.

Comment: @fgp, yes, you're right.

Comment: @JohnLawler OK, I guess you could define things that may. Still makes very little sense to me though - calling the one verbal form that is inflected the *main verb* seems much more sensible to me, and it's what all other languages that I know of do...

Comment: @fgp, you are not alone.  Here (from John's website) is a paper by Ross which argues that inflected auxiliaries are main verbs: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/AuxasMV.pdf

Comment: Yes, one can do that. But that makes the analysis of the sentences very abstract, with almost everything being an abstract predicate (this is the level of abstraction where performative verbs are sposta appear). Generally speaking, though, "main verb" is not a term with a precise meaning -- it means the one you're concentrating on, either because it's inflected or because it's the only one that has its own meaning and isn't part of the grammar.